# Can I solve this differential equation using Euler's equation？

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The S-ODE:

> $$(2x+3)y''=4y'$$

Because the $y''$coefficient is a function of $x$ and it is changing, so I consider using the Euler substitution.

Here's my method:
$$
2x+3=e^t, \quad t=\ln{(2x+3)}, \quad 2x + 3 > 0\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{2x+3}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{4}{(2x+3)^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\\
\text{ Hence, } \quad \frac{4}{2x+3}\cdot y''(t)=\frac{8}{2x+3} \cdot y'(t)\\
$$
Finally, I used the method of solving the second-order constant coefficient linear equation to obtain the answer
$$
y=C_1+C_2(2x+3)^2
$$

Is my method incorrect?

Comment: Why not introduce a new variable $p := y'$ and use the method of variable seperation?

Answer (score 1):

This method works, but you make an error here:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{2x+3}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{4}{(2x+3)^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}.
$$
The second line is not correct. You should have
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}&=& \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2}{2x+3}\frac{dy}{dt}\right) = -\frac{4}{(2x+3)^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{4}{(2x+3)^2}\frac{d^2y}{d^2t}
\\ &=& \frac{4}{(2x+3)^2}\left(\frac{d^2y}{d^2t}-\frac{dy}{dt}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Remember, $d^2f/dx^2$ is a shorthand for $d(df/dx)/dx$. When changing variables, you will get extra terms that have to be differentiated too. You can get the general form from the chain rule and product rules
$$
\frac{d^2f(g(x))}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[f'(g(x)g'(x)\right] = g'(x)^2 f''(g(x)) + g''(x)f'(g(x))
$$
Now follow the same method and you'll get the correct answer:
$$
y = c_1(2x+3)^3 + c_2.
$$

Comment: Thank you!I made a low-level mistake when calculating the derivative

Answer (score 0):

> I assume you mean $\color\green{y'} = C_1 + C_2(2x + 3)^2$ and **not** $\color\red{y} = C_1 + C_2(2x + 3)^2$.

While your working out is in the right direction, there is an easier method (separation of variables). In truth, the ODE is of first-order kind as the lowest order term is $y'$.

Hence, let $t = y'$,

$$(2x + 3)t' = 4t \\ \to \dfrac{t'}{t} = \dfrac{4}{2x+3} \\ \to t = y'= C_1(2x + 3)^2$$

I think the rest  is clear.

Comment: Thank you!I just made a low-level mistake when calculating the second derivative which lead me to an error in the result。